# how to take last text from a string separated by "|"

Tags: javascript, separator

I am having a string same like

```
a|b|c|d|e|....|n
```

I need to get the last item in this string in javascript. There may be n number of items in this string.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: split it on `"|"` and get the last item in the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit verbose but probably the most straightforward way:

```
var str = 'a|b|c|e|f';
var arr = str.split('|'); // split into array
alert(arr[arr.length-1]); // get last element of the array
```

Answer (score 8):

```
yourString.split('|').slice(-1)[0]
```

Comment: `yourString.split('|').pop()` could be shorter, no? ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop))

Comment: @FabrícioMatté: oh good point, please add that as your own answer. =)

Comment: Nah dw, the `.pop()` is just a shortened version of your `slice(-1)[0]`, both are virtually the same but mine has an abstraction level more. `=]`

Comment: I wouldn't say they're exactly the same. `.slice(-1)` is making a copy of a 1-length subarray of the array, then taking the 0th element. `.pop()` is mutating the array and returning the last element, which is why I don't normally use `.pop()` because of mutations, but in this case it would be mutating the intermediate array returned by `.split('|')` which would be thrown away anyway. Though the most efficient solution would be to use `.lastIndexOf`

Answer (score 1):

If your string is very long, you will want to avoid using `.split('|')` since that will create a new array with potentially many elements. I like `.split('|')` because it's unambiguous what you're trying to do, but if you want efficiency, you can use:

```
yourString.substr(yourString.lastIndexOf('|')+1)
```

(This will even work in corner cases like `"abc"`, `"abc|"`, and `"|abc"`, since lastIndexOf returns -1 if nothing is found.)

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "a|b|c|d|e|f|g";

var arr = str.split("|");
var last_item = arr[arr.length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

And now for something completely different!

```
/(?:\||^)([^|]*)$/.exec(str)[1]
```

Comment: Also, `/(\||^)([^|]*)$/.exec(str)[2]` is the shortest possible way.

Comment: @RakeshHolkar: Hm, how are you trying it? Works fine for me.

Comment: @RakeshHolkar: I *am* testing it and it's working. Thought I made that pretty clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try it......

```
str='asfd|asdf|as|df|as|asdf|asf';
str.split('|').slice(b.length-1)[0]
```